# Automatic Data type conversion in pandas for each cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["1","2","aj"],"B":["1.5555","899999999999999999999999","dfhasdi"]})
```

which gives output

```
    A                         B
0   1                    1.5555
1   2  899999999999999999999999
2  aj                   dfhasdi
```

The data Type for each cell is

```
               A              B
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
1  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
2  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
```

The required data type for each cell is

```
               A                B
0  <class 'int'>  <class 'float'>
1  <class 'int'>    <class 'int'>
2  <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>
```

I did this so far

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
```

Which doesn't change the data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for elementwise check with double `try-except` statement if need distingush between integers, floats and strings in same column(s):

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except Exception:
        try:
            return float(x)
        except Exception:
            return x


df = df.applymap(f)
print (df)
    A                         B
0   1                    1.5555
1   2  899999999999999999999999
2  aj                   dfhasdi

print (df.applymap(type))
               A                B
0  <class 'int'>  <class 'float'>
1  <class 'int'>    <class 'int'>
2  <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>
```

Close to your solution, but if mix strings with integers get floats in solution:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(df)
print (df)
     A                           B
0  1.0                      1.5555
1  2.0  899999999999999958056960.0
2   aj                     dfhasdi
    
print (df.applymap(type))
                 A                B
0  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>
1  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>
2    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>
```

It working better if same types (string repr):

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(df)
print (df)
   A                           B
0  1                      1.5555
1  2  899999999999999958056960.0
2  4                     dfhasdi

print (df.applymap(type))
               A                B
0  <class 'int'>  <class 'float'>
1  <class 'int'>  <class 'float'>
2  <class 'int'>    <class 'str'>
```

Comment: You can use `pd.to_numeric(x, errors='ignore')` in your `f`.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych - Unfortuantely not

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych - because `errors='ignore'` means if get error, return same values (not changed)

Comment: That's what you do with your exception catching, don't you? The only problem is that `pd.to_numeric` would return numpy's `int`s and `float`s. (Which fails on this integer that is too big for numpy's int). Apart from that, it works the same

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych - Not sure if understand.

Comment: I'm saying that `def f(x): return pd.to_numeric(x, errors='ignore')` would work the same apart from having numpy's types instead of pure pythons.